# How to add dynamic tooltip to a image control which is in gridview?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview, tooltip

Iam having Image control in gridview as

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnInfo" runat="server" ImageUrl="info.jpg" ToolTip="Button info" title="Info" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID") %>' CommandName="Info"  />
```

This is my grid views image button where i get my ids of each row dynamic as

```
   imgbtnInfo0
   imgbtnInfo1
   imgbtnInfo2
```

In these way depending on how many rows i will get ID of image button,

I just want to generate Tool Tip Dynamically using Ajax or server side,i don't have any idea
Can any one help

Comment: Have the tooltips the same text for all the images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the text is the same for all the images you can assing a css class to the image control:

```
 <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnInfo" CssClass="imgtooltip" runat="server" />
```

and then call the `tooltip` function of the jQuery UI framework:

```
$('.imgtooltip').tooltip();
```

In case each row has to have its own tooltip text, you can set the `title` property at server side. In your case, since you are using a `GridView` you could use the `onrowdatabound` event.

```
<asp:gridview 
    onrowdatabound="myGridView_RowDataBound" 
    runat="server">
  </asp:gridview>


void myGridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

   if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {
      // Set the title text
      e.Row.Cells[yourImageIndex].Title = "yourTooltipText";
   }
 }
```

If you know the `title` text at client side (javasctip) you also can set this value using a jQuery `each` method looping throwgh your gridview table.

**EDIT:**

If you need to get the tooltip text from a database I recommend you to set this value in server side code. You can bind it to a custom html attribute.

```
tool='<%# Eval("toolAtServerSideDataSource") %>'
```

This example shows how to set the stored attribute named `tool` as a tooltip:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/y6rvs/1/

Comment: can you please explain some code on client side.., i want each row with diff tool tip

Comment: @þÍńķ How do you know or get the tooltip text?

Comment: I need to get names from data base and bind it

Comment: Ok in this case, put the tooltip got from the DB into your DataSource and bind it to a custom html attribute defined in you html markup GridView control. Then use jquery to get this value and set as a tooltip. Check my edit.